# Scraper for Ugolini & C miniGel L4

Tags: equipment, ice-cream

I have recently inherited a "Ugolini & C miniGel L4" gelato or ice cream maker that my mother bought in the early 1980s (Williams and Sonoma began importing this model in 1979 but stopped sometime in the 1900s). This machine includes a plastic (or plastic-like) scraper that needs to be replaced. Where can I get replacements for this part?

[image: damaged scraper]

(My father also has this model ice cream maker, but tells me the only sources he knows stopped carrying these in the early 2000s. He says he would be using his, except he needs the blades as well.)

Comment: Contact the company?  They still exist and sell a ‘maintenance kit’for the mini  gel: https://www.ugoliniusa.com/product-page/maintenance-kits

Comment: Thank you for that link. I'm trying it. I had contacted the Italian offices as that was the site I found (with no response). The current Minigel models are *very* different from the ones I am working with, but I'll see how this goes.